# Plotting facetgrid plots in seaborn with smoothing

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, ggplot2, seaborn, facet

I have a pandas dataframe a snippet of which is shown below:-

[image: pandas dataframe]
I wish to recreate the graphs shown below in Seaborn. These graphs were created in R using ggplot, but I am working with pandas/matplotlib/seaborn.
[image: ggplot graphs with smoothing]

Essentially the graphs summarize the variables(mi,steps,st...) grouped by sensor id, with hours to the event on the x-axis. Additionally and most importantly, there is smoothing performed by stat_smooth() within ggplot. I have included a snippet of my ggplot code.

```
 step.plot <- ggplot(data=cdays, aes(x=dfc, y=steps, col=legid)) + 
  ggtitle('time to event' +
  labs(x="Days from event", y='Number of steps') +
  stat_smooth(method='loess', span=0.2, formula=y~x) +
  geom_vline(mapping=aes(xintercept=0), color='blue') +
  theme(legend.position="none")
```

Answer (score 4):

here is how I would do it. Bear in mind that I had to make assumptions about the structure of your data, so please review what I did before applying it.

**Creating some simulated data**

```
subject = np.repeat(np.repeat([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 4), 31)
time = np.tile(np.repeat(np.arange(-15, 16, 1), 4), 5)
sensor = np.tile([1, 2, 3, 4], 31*5)
measure1 = subject*20 + time*(5-sensor) - time**2*(sensor-2)*0.1 + (time >= 0)*np.random.normal(100*(sensor-2), 10, 620) + np.random.normal(0, 10, 620)
measure2 = subject*10 + time*(2-sensor) - time**2*(sensor-4)*0.1 + (time >= 0)*np.random.normal(50*(sensor-1), 10, 620) + np.random.normal(0, 8, 620)
measure3 = time**2*(sensor-1)*0.1 + (time >= 0)*np.random.normal(50*(sensor-3), 10, 620) + np.random.normal(0, 8, 620)
measure4 = time**2*(sensor-1)*0.1  + np.random.normal(0, 8, 620)
```

**Putting it in a long form dataset for plotting**

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(subject=subject, time=time, sensor=sensor, measure1=measure1,
                      measure2=measure2, measure3=measure3, measure4=measure4))

df = pd.melt(df, id_vars=["sensor", "subject", "time"], 
             value_vars=["measure1", "measure2","measure3", "measure4"],
             var_name="measure")
```

**Creating the plot, without smoothing**

```
g = sns.FacetGrid(data=df, col="measure", col_wrap=2)
g.map_dataframe(sns.tsplot, time="time", value="value", condition="sensor", unit="subject", color="deep")
g.add_legend(title="Sensor Number")
g.set_xlabels("Days from Event")
g.set_titles("{col_name}")
plt.show()
```

[image: Plotted data, before smoothing]

*Plotted data, before smoothing*

**Now let's use statsmodels to smooth the data.**

*Please review this part, this is where I made assumptions about the sampling unit (I assume that the sampling unit is the subject, and therefore treat sensors and measure types as conditions).*

```
from statsmodels.nonparametric.smoothers_lowess import lowess
dfs = []
for sens in df.sensor.unique():
    for meas in df.measure.unique():
        # One independent smoothing per Sensor/Measure condition.
        df_filt = df.loc[(df.sensor == sens) & (df.measure == meas)]
        # Frac is equivalent to span in R
        filtered = lowess(df_filt.value, df_filt.time, frac=0.2) 
        df_filt["filteredvalue"] = filtered[:,1]
        dfs.append(df_filt)
df = pd.concat(dfs)
```

[image: Plotted data, after smoothing]

*Plotted data, after smoothing*

From there you can tweak your plot however you like. Tell me if you have any question.

Comment: Thank you for your response, this is what I was looking for. I have recreated your steps and got my dataframe shaped similar to what you have shown. however, when trying to plot I get the error           ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape                                  This is the line where it breaks:-    plot.map_dataframe(sns.tsplot,time='hrs_to_calving',value='value',condition='sensor_id',unit='subject',color='deep')

Comment: This is because your data has to have one unique point per time/condition/unit/measure. If you have more than one, tsplot encounters an error when reshaping your data in long form (I. E. One line per time/condition/unit /measure.

Comment: thanks, that makes sense. To explain further, the last two letters of my subject are the sensor_ids of which i have 3 types i.e. BL, BR and FL. I am thinking that maybe I need to find the mean value for each time for each type of sensor_id to achieve what I want. Do you mind having a look at a csv dump of my dataframe to see if there is another way to achieve this?https://github.com/xjackx/Programming-Projects_Assignments/blob/master/jupyter%20notebooks/24hr_plotdata.csv

Comment: i managed to transform my data set be pivoting it so now there is only one value associated with a time index for each sensor and for each variable being tracked. I have not been able to adapt the plotting side of your code though. can you help?                     pivot_df=pd.pivot_table(df,index=['hrs_to_calving'],values=['mi','steps','standing_time','standing_change','lying_bouts','activity_index'],columns=['sensor_id'],aggfunc=[np.mean])